# Adding ngAnimate throwing injector error

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I can't seem to get ngAnimate working properly. When I don't include the module, I can use CSS transitions, but I want to use jQuery's slideToggle(). From what I understand, for that I have to inject the module?

I'm using Angular 1.3.14 if that matters. I have the following definition in my main file:

```
var app = angular.module('gamersplane', ['controllers', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'angularFileUpload']);
```

Then I have this in a separate file:

```
app.animation('#withdrawEarly', [function () {
    return {
        addClass: function (element, className, done) {
            $(element).slideToggle();
        },
        removeClass: function (element, className, done) {
            $(element).slideToggle();
        }
    }
}]);
```

I don't know if the animate works or not because I get this error in my console:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=gamersplane&p1=Err…F%2Fgamersplane.local%2Fjavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D1.0.0%3A18%3A179)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you haven't includeded [angular-animate.js](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) . See the installation section .

Comment: You mean included the file, using script tags, right? If so, yes, I have the file included, and its version matches my Angular version. If I hadn't included it, the CSS translations wouldn't have worked when my ng-show changed, right?

Comment: Yeah, but do you get this error only when you add 'ngAnimate' to dependencies to the module ?

Comment: Yup, only when I add it to the dependencies. I've double checked that the file is uploaded, and it is.